# The fastest way to loop over 3 cases

Tags: c++

We have integers X, Y and Z. We should find `(x, y, z)`, where `x * z > y^2` with the following constraints: `0 < x <= X`, `0 < y <= Y` and `0 < z <= Z` as well as `1 <= X, Y, Z <= 1000`.

A loop will probably not be the best solution. Looking for performance wise.

```cpp
int main() 
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s); // 2 3 4

    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::vector<int> v((std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)), std::istream_iterator<int>());

    int X = v[0];
    int Y = v[1];
    int Z = v[2];

    unsigned long long count = 0;
    for (int y = 1; y <= Y; y++)
        for (int x = 1; x <= X; x++)
            for (int z = 1; z <= Z; z++)
            {
                count += x * z > y * y;
            }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If we input `3 3 3`, it does that:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 1 3
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
```

Comment: I probably don't understand the question, because I would just pick `y = 1` and that would satisfy all conditions. Give us an example of input and desired output.

Comment: @Dialecticus I assume this is more an "find all integers which fulfill ..." task. (But at the moment this is just an "please do my homework" question.)

Comment: Updated the question with working code but not "optimized".

Comment: Ok, that is a valid first attempt @nop. Did you try out how long it takes for `X=Y=Z=1000`? Is it worth optimizing? One thing you could easily optimize is that the most inner loop can be calculated directly by just dividing `y*y/x` (try this for small numbers and think about why this is true)

Comment: Also think about commutativity and that one valid solution instantly yields more solutions

Comment: @chtz, yes it should be optimized because it timeouts.

Comment: It does just 1e9 comparisions, so it should not take more than a few seconds. Did you compile with optimizations enabled (e.g, `-O2` with gcc/clang)

Comment: @chtz, I don't have impact over the compiler. It should be solved by the code.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the types or I don't know.

Comment: You don't need a third loop. Instead of incrementing `count` by one find a way to add more than one in every step.

Comment: @Dialecticus, I currently can't think of it. Otherwise I got your idea.

Comment: I am going to venture and say that no loops are needed whatsoever. I think you might come up with a formula. Just a hunch

Comment: `1 1 1` but `1*1 > 1²` is false.

Comment: `x*z > y²` with strictly positive, it is equivalent to `z > y²/x` so z is in `0 <= y²/x < z <= Z` so `count += std::max(0, Z - y²/x)`